# Not operator not working on my javascript code

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm very confusing about javascript operators. Look at this:

```
localStorage.setItem('isValidUserCpf', false);


    alert(localStorage.getItem('isValidUserCpf'));
    alert(!localStorage.getItem('isValidUserCpf'));
    alert(!(localStorage.getItem('isValidUserCpf')));

    if (localStorage.getItem('isValidUserCpf') == false){
        alert('notEntering');
    }
```

Why all alerts are printing "false"? And why my if condition is not working? I really don't know what is my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only store strings in local storage, so when you tried to store `false` it is converted to a string `"false"`.
Your first alert shows this string. The others shows this string applied to not operator ([`!"false" === false`](http://jsfiddle.net/T5kVL/)) and the false value is converted to a string and shown in the alert.

What you can do is serialize you data to store it in localstorage

```
localStorage.setItem('isValidUserCpf', JSON.strinify(false));
var isValidUserCpf = localStorage.getItem('isValidUserCpf');
alert(isValidUserCpf);
alert(JSON.parse(isValidUserCpf));
alert(!JSON.parse(isValidUserCpf));

if (isValidUserCpf == false){
    alert('notEntering');
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JSON

Answer (score 1):

```
localStorage.setItem('isValidUserCpf', false);
```

`false` is stored as a string.

```
alert(localStorage.getItem('isValidUserCpf'));
```

alert with the string value `"false"`

```
alert(!localStorage.getItem('isValidUserCpf'));
```

alert with the boolean `!"false"` which is also `false` in boolean

```
alert(!(localStorage.getItem('isValidUserCpf')));
```

same as above one

---

Please test with

```
localStorage.setItem('isValidUserCpf', true);
```

you will see "true", false, false

I am not sure for what environment you are testing, you can see the value of `localStorage` with `console.log(localStorage)`

Comment: thanks for helping me, now my code works. But I do not understand this sentence: alert(!localStorage.getItem('isValidUserCpf'));
alert with the boolean !"false" which is also false in boolean.
Can you explain it to me?

Comment: if you test `if( "whatever" )`, the condition will result `true`. if you test `if( "false" )`, the condition will result `true` too. --- on the other hand, `if( !"whatever" )` will result `false`. NOTE `if( "" )` - a null string - results `false`.

Comment: Thanks @Tun Zarni Kyaw, now I understand what really happens!!

Answer (score 1):

The keys and values for local storage are strings as defined by the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-interface). Non-empty strings are `true` when evaluated as a boolean, thus negating it would result in a `false` result. Similarly the string "false" is not the same as the boolean `false`. If you change the condition to compare strings, it will evaluate as you expect - working fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/79pF5/

```
if (localStorage.getItem('isValidUserCpf') === 'false') {
   alert('notEntering');
}
```